# Change color of readonly cells using angular ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular UI Grid for ui-grid in my project
I want to make some cells read only.
cellEditableCondition(for row)  and enableCellEdit (for column), I am able to achieve it. This is working fine.

But Now I want to change color of all Cells which are readonly just after page load, How can I achieve this.
I understand cellEditableCondition field only execute when user click on cell in grid.
any pointer also appreciated.

Comment: you could use ng-class directive inside your custom celltemplate and mark them disabled (css readonly and background-color)

Answer (score 0):

I used cellClass in columnDef to achieve this
its working perfectly fine

```
cellClass: function (grid, row) {
                    if(myCondition){
                        return 'test-class1';
                    }else{
                        return 'test-class2';
                    }
                },
```